# Custom Keyboard in iphone

Tags: iphone, iphone-softkeyboard

i have to develope an application in which
i have to add two buttons within the keyboard

i need to know how to implement it.

please help me.

i will be thank full.

Answer (score 2):

I have been watching the iphone classes that are in itunes from Stanford University.  They had someone from Apple there and asked this question and they said that you cannot change the keyboard except to change the return key to one of the other settings for it.  I do like what Facebook and Tweetie (the guy that wrote this also talked in the iphone classes) have done to add buttons.  They stated that overall Apple wanted a consistant look and feel to things like the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. You can do what the Facebook and Tweetie apps do, though, and add an additional set of controls right above the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the latest iOS version. Check the inputView property of UITextField for details.